# Seeing if mean difference is statistically significant for thousands of samples in R

Tags: r, statistics

My proficiency in R is just around basic so bear with me if what I'm asking for is not possible on the software.

I have data like the following:

```
x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
5  4  3  9  8  7
0  1  9  4  2  1
2  1  2  3  2  2
3  3  1  2  3  4
```

And this goes on for up to about 27,000 rows like this.
You can think of these as responses in a clinical trial where x1,x2,x3 represent group x of patients and y1,y2,y3 part of group y of patients.
Someone asked me if they can see if the mean difference between group x and group y is statistically significant for every one of the ~27,000 rows (presumably using a t-test), and if they can show a p-value as a separate column. So it would look like this:

```
x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 p-value
5  4  3  9  8  7  0.7780
0  1  9  4  2  1  0.2404
2  1  2  3  2  2  0.2311
3  3  1  2  3  4  0.1113
```

To me it seems unreasonable to do this but I'm wondering if there's anyway I can basically perform ~27,000 t.tests (between the means of x1+x2+x3 and y1+y2+y3) and have a column showing each test's p-value as a neighboring column. Or perhaps even if there was another, better way to gauge the significance without using a t.test. Thank you.

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is to find a statistician (i.e. Someone with a PhD in statistics) and have them do some consulting for you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I would recommend against it.  When doing this many t-tests at once, the p-values really won't mean quite what you think they mean.  Research the multiple comparisons problem.  Depending on what you are trying to do, @joran is probably right - you should consult a statistician.  This is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that groups are of equal lengths:

```
getPValue <- function(row)
{
  l <- length(row)/2
  x <- row[1:l]
  y <- row[-(1:l)]
  fit <- t.test(x,y)
  return(fit$p.value)
}

data <- cbind(data,apply(data,1,getPValue))
```

EDIT:

And if you want also to attach absolute mean difference which is being tested for each row, you can use:

```
getPValue <- function(row)
{
  l <- length(row)/2
  x <- row[1:l]
  y <- row[-(1:l)]
  fit <- t.test(x,y)
  return(fit$p.value)
}

getMeanDiff <- function(row)
{
  l <- length(row)/2
  x <- row[1:l]
  y <- row[-(1:l)]
  return(abs(mean(x)-mean(y)))
}

diff <- apply(data,1,getMeanDiff)
p.value <-apply(data,1,getPValue)

data <- data.frame(cbind(data,diff,p.value))
```